# WPF Load collection with rest of foreign keys even if one is null or 0

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, design-patterns

*Note: I'm using EF6, and MahApps.Metro*

I'm getting an error injecting ForeignKey objects into the class that has them (properly) annotated.

Let's say I have a model

```
public class Image : ObservableObject
{
    private Type _type;
    private int _typeId;
    private Code _code;
    private int _codeId;

    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public virtual Type Type 
    {
        get => _type;
        set => Set(()=> Type, ref _type, value);
    }

    public int TypeId
    {
       get => _typeId;
       set => Set(()=> TypeId, ref _typeId, value);
    }   

    [ForeignKey("CodeId")]
    public virtual Code Code
    {
        get => _code;
        set => Set(()=> Code , ref _code, value);
    }

    public int CodeId
    {
       get => _codeId;
       set => Set(()=> CodeId, ref _codeId, value);
    }
}
```

And a repository method :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Image>> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        return await context.Images.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

If I use this method of retrieving database objects, debugging my model shows that all of the ForeignKey objects throw a ***System.ObjectDisposedException***.

The reason (I think) this happens is due to me not adding `.Including(image => image.Code).Include(image => image.Type)` to the return statement.

Why I'm not adding is due to the fact that sometimes the Image class contains Code, but sometimes it **doesn't**. If I try to load list of Images with .Include and class doesn't have a Code, the repository returns ***an empty list***.

So is there a way to not add .Include() methods but have the context ignore the "unexistant" foreign keys?

I'd love any advice over my repository and model design. (probably a question for stack exchange)

Comment: Where do you get the exception? In the debugger only?

Comment: Debugger only, yes, but of course the FK property is not present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown when a navigation property is accessed because you use lazy loading, and there is no `DbContext` around to get the related entities from after your `GetAll()` method has returned.

You could either use eager loading to load all related entities upfront:

```
.Include(image => image.Code).Include(image => image.Type)
```

Or you could disable the lazy loading by either removing the `virtual` keyword from the navigation properties of your `Image` class or by setting a flag on the `Configuration` property of the `DbContext`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Image>> GetAll()
{
    using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return await context.Images.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

This of course you means that you won't be able to get the type or code of an Image without explicitly loading these entities: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Yeah I got all of these from Stack and Docs from microsoft, the question was whether is possible to load collection if one of the .Include() methods do not get an object from the respectable FK table? Because if I say .Include(t=> t.Type) and the types table does not contain the specified FK, the entire list returns empty (event if other includes return a value)

Comment: The answer to that question is no.

Comment: Aight, thanks. I'll do the Includes and skip the ones I know that might not have a present FK.